# Best way to store ISO8601 in datetime column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I'm passing my Rails controller a parameter that has a value of:

```
time = "2011-11-14T23:53:14.000Z"
```

For my app, I have a a database called "Reminders" with a `remind_at` column, which is a `datetime` column just like `created_at` and `modified_at`.

However I can't figure out how I should save this. I imagine it would be something like:

```
r = Reminder.create(:remind_at => time)
r.save
```

But this does not save it properly. Am I supposde to do some conversion of some sort first? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to convert it into a Time object:

```
time = Time.parse("2011-11-14T23:53:14.000Z")
```